# Start program after login in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, autostart, sh

I try to run Jira after Ubuntu start. In `/etc/rc.local` I wrote this:

```
cd atlassian/jira/bin; ./start-jira.sh
```

(all directories wrote properly)
Where is my mistake?

Full `rc.local`:

[gists](https://gist.github.com/NovikovViktor/9c1639a17f583b7baa36)

Comment: Tried absolute paths instead of relative ones?

Comment: You need to give full path and redirect output to log file to troubleshoot further. Is it headless machine ? If you use it to Graphical login , then you can use the greeter program to add to start up script.

Comment: @muru, attlassian folder lay at home folder, i think atlassian/jira/bin its properly path or not?

Comment: @excluded_once it is in your home folder, and rc.local is run as root, with the current directory being `/`. You should give the full path: `/home/excluded_once/atlassian/...`.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the bin subdirectory of your JIRA installation directory and execute the appropriate file. After this press enter then type the below,

start-jira.sh

To start JIRA using the service, you can execute the /etc/init.d/jira script.